# Regulator Circuit 30-300v for 3-phase generator

Tags: voltage-regulator, generator

I need help with the rest of the circuit to control the field in the generator (it is a 400v 3-phase 50Hz generator). I have looked around online and only find car generators 12v and 24v.

What I'm trying to do is vary the voltage so it gives 30-300v. The generator has no slip rings but an exciter stator.

[image]

Comment: A PWM driven MOSFET would avoid the 11 W power loss in Q2. Is this an option for you?

Comment: Have a heatsink on Q2 so it's ok. Don't you need a microcontroller to generate pwm for the MOSFET? I'm not very good at writing programs @Jens

Comment: Got the circuit working reasonably well with an op-amp after a lot of back and forth. It was able to charge the lithium battery (164V 150Ah).
Will draw a circuit diagram of how I did it. How do I add more pictures to the question?